# Is the Standard Model, in some sense, special relativity plus everything possible?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, lagrangian-formalism, symmetry, standard-model

I found [this intro to QFT on YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MmG2ah5Df4g&t=106s) really helpful (and apparently I'm not the only one).  Let my try to summarize it:

We start with Minkowski space.  We want to add a field to it, but there are only certain mathematical objects that respect Lorentz symmetry.  These include (complex) numbers, (bi-)spinors, and (4-)vectors.  For each such object, we add a field.  But some of these objects contain their own internal symmetries, such that distinct versions/instances of them are possible.  So we include all such instances (e.g. we have the various types of fermions for the spinors, and for each fermion we have an anti-matter field).  Next, we let each field assume every conceivable spacetime configuration simultaneously, subject to conservation constraints that are inherent to either spacetime or the objects: energy-momentum, charge.

Then there is the question of how these fields shall evolve.  We have them evolve according to the quantum action principle, and once again, the function that determines evolution (the Lagrangian) contains every possible term that respects all the aforementioned symmetries (I don't think they said this in the video, but I've read it elsewhere).

The only part of this picture that appears to impose a meaningful restriction is the quantum action principle in itself -- the idea that these infinite configurations do not diverge indefinitely, but "recombine" according to the Lagrangian phase change.  But I have a vague sense that even this is almost a trivial constraint -- it's basically the simplest way these configurations can connect with each other, and if they didn't, it would be a pretty meaningless theory, wouldn't it?

Is this a valid way to think of QFT?  Are we just filling in Minkowski space with everything we possibly could?  And is the class of allowable mathematical objects, then, really just the Clifford algebra of Minkowski space (the "spacetime algebra")?  If so, is there an online source that approaches QFT from this angle?  Or if not, then where does this interpretation break down?

P.S.  While watching the video, I realized for the first time that the scalar (Higgs) field has only one instance, while the vector (photon, gluon, W, Z) and spinor (neutrino, electron, up quark, down quark) fields have 4 each (ignoring generations).  Is this related at all to spacetime being 4D?

Comment: One comment is that QFT does not encompass "everything possible" compatible with special relativity. In a sense, quantum field theories are the simplest possible quantum mechanical theories that we can come up with obeying the constraints imposed by special relativity, but there are other theories compatible with special relativity which are not quantum field theories. String theory is a famous such example. See this (very accessible) redacted talk of Weinberg on the subject: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-th/9702027

Comment: Even within the framework of gauge theories, the Standard Model is not uniquely determined by theoretical constraints. For example, it would be perfectly allowed *theoretically* to have a different gauge group (say $SU(27)$ instead of $SU(3)$ for the strong interactions), or a different number of fermion generations, or to break the electroweak symmetry using technicolor instead of via the Higgs mechanism. There is a lot of empirical input to the Standard Model that is not explained theoretically.

Comment: Why do people downvote genuine questions like these?

Comment: [Then there's supersymmetry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coleman%E2%80%93Mandula_theorem#Supersymmetry).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the strictest sense, the answer to your question is *no*. But, there are some related kinds of things which sort of follow your line of thought

- For gauge theories to be well-defined, there is a certain technical requirement called 'anomaly cancellation', that tells you that the quantum effects don't spoil your gauge theory. This puts a lot of constraints on the type of matter that is allowed for your theory, take a look at David Tong's [notes](http://www.damtp.cam.ac.uk/user/tong/gaugetheory/3anom.pdf) (around page 172 for example). You can make various statements like "if the gauge group is assumed to be $SU(3) \times SU(2) \times U(1)$ and you want a chiral theory, the simplest matter content is given by the standard model" (up to the fact that there are three generations).
- In Effective Field Theories, there is often a 'from the ground up' mentality, where you write down in your lagrangian (what you use to describe the theory) all terms consistent with the symmetries you wish to impose. An example is chiral perturbation theory, the theory describing light hadrons.